# I'm trying to get attribute in table row

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, attributes

I'm trying to delete a row from table.

[image]

But i need to access the attribute "news-uid" on each row

[image]

This is the code for setting the news-uid attribute to each row

```
  var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);

    var titleCell = row.insertCell(0);
    var contentCell = row.insertCell(1);
    var imgCell = row.insertCell(2);
    var publisherCell = row.insertCell(3);
    var dateCell = row.insertCell(4);
    var actionCell = row.insertCell(5);
    var editBtn = '<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editNewsModal"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>';
    var deletetActionBtn = '<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteNewsModal"> <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>';

    row.setAttribute('news-uid', doc.id);
    imgCell.innerHTML = '<img src="' + doc.data().newsImage + '" width="100px" height="100px" />';
    titleCell.innerHTML = doc.data().newsTitle;
    contentCell.innerHTML = doc.data().newsContent;
    publisherCell.innerHTML = doc.data().newsPublisher;
    dateCell.innerHTML = doc.data().timestamp.toDate();
    actionCell.innerHTML = editBtn + '  ' + deletetActionBtn;
```

This is the function to delete the row

```
const deletetBtn = document.querySelector('#deleteBtn');
deletetBtn?.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let uid = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('news-uid');
    console.log(uid);

    // db.collection('news').doc(uid).delte();
});
```

But it's not getting the news-uid

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Please create a [MRE] within your question. Presumably the parentElement of the button is actually a table cell, not the table row.

Comment: Have you considered  using the `data-` attribute?

Comment: Ask yourself what is the parent element of deleteBtn and whether it has a new-uid. Also, there is a typo of 'deletetBtn' please fix this.

Comment: Why you write 'deletetBtn?.addEventListener' with '?'

Comment: Because optional chaining allows us to write broken code without error!